# show custom image as marker on react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to show my custom image as a Marker in `react-native-maps` as you see below, but it doesn't show anything on the map

```
<MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        region={this.state.region}
        ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }}
        zoomControlEnabled={true}
    >


        <MapView.Marker
            identifier="destination"
            coordinate={direction.destination}
            anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
        >
            <View style={{ width: 10, height: 10 }}>
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/destination-3.png')} style={{ width: 10, height: 10 }}/>
            </View>

        </MapView.Marker>
    </MapView>
```

I can see any element inside `<MapView.Marker>` but `<Image/>` and `<ImageBackground>` . It's becoming a trouble.

Comment: you can use image prop of Marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution worked for me was using `svg` means render the image inside svg insteade of rendering by  react native Image directly

```
   <Svg
            height="50"
            width="50"
            key={2000}
        >
            <Image
                key={200}
                width="90%"
                height="90%"
                href={require('../assets/images/destination-3.png')}
            />
        </Svg>
```

and i have rendered this svg more than two time in page if i wan to see it at first run!!!(and give negative top and left with position absolute for hiding that )

Comment: This worked for me in terms of using SVG image. Thanks @iman

Answer (score 2):

i have used GIMP (Linux alternative for Photoshop ) to minimize my image into a icon size (open image in GIMP -> Image -> Scale -> give Size you want. ) and my code is like this

```
<MapView
      initialRegion={this.state.loc}
      region={this.state.loc}
      style={styles.map}     
      >
      <Marker coordinate={{
            latitude: 7.093546,
            longitude: 79.993703,}}
            image={require('./img/icon.png')} >
      </Marker>
</MapView>
```

Hope this Helps..

[image: we are showing a location of a Train]

Comment: if i need to customize the image { width and height} how to do that if i use Image={..} props

Comment: @DevAS are you able to find customize image size with image props ?